# I want to copy a range of cells and paste them to another sheet dependent on a drop down selection and activated using a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Export to sheet button but I can't get it working correctly.
I selects the correct cells to copy but can't then transpose them on to selected sheet that appears in the drop down box in cell A1, I then also need it to paste on the next available row in that specific sheet. The problem is that I can't just list the sheets in VBA as the list in the drop down box changes. I have tried several ways to with no success. If someone could help it would be great

```
Sub Button2_Click()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:x2").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1!A1").Range("a:x")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the sheet name in your worksheet function.

This might work.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

'Copying the Data
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:x2").Copy

'Pasting the data
' What we were missing was to pass the name of the tab dynamically. Now this code will pick up the name that appears in the Cell A1.

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value).Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Also in the paste range you only need to put the first cell range to paste values.

To paste the Transposed Values check the function **PasteSpecial** with Transpose property set to True.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't help I have list of 40+ sheets in the dropdown box and I need to paste to 1 of those sheets depending on which sheet is showing in the dropdown + plus list length changes as more sheets are added

Comment: I understood that you want to paste data in Cell A1, but you want to pick the tab name from A1. I have amended the answer accordingly. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more code I have tried for the issue but still does not seem to work.

Sub ExportButton1()
'
' ExportButton1 Macro
' Exports Data to staff sheet from drop down box
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data")
  'On Error Resume Next
    'If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("H2"), Target) Is Nothing) Then _

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Range("H2"))

copySheet.Range("G5:AA5").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

'I have found another way around the problem to copy paste cells to certain sheet then on 'staff sheet a formula in a table to tests column A value on data sheet for name and only 'transpose those rows

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("A2:J2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

End Sub

'Formula on staff sheet is -=IF(Sheet3!A:A="Column1",Sheet3!$B:$B,"")

Comment: Thank you for your help much appreciated